# databinding to ejs file in node.js not working

Tags: node.js

It sounds like in ejx file, I cannot display the value from the array I passed in.

I am trying to create a data binding proof of concept with node.js, express, where I passed data to ejs file to be displayed in the ejs file. I followed several posts and I could not make it working with my example.

In the router (index.js) i have the following code:

```
request.on('row', function (columns) {
const datas = [];
columns.forEach(function (column) {
   if (column.value === null) {
         console.log('NULL');
    } else {
         datas.push (column.value)
    }
 });
 datas.forEach(function (value) {
         console.log(value)
 });
 res.render('test.ejs', {
       "players": datas
  }
 )
 });
```

When I run this code, it shows the value in the console in json
[{"id":2,"first_name":"...","last_name":"...","position":"...","number":...,"image":"xyz","userName":"..."}] (based on the sql data schema)

I tried the following code in .ejs file to display the data

```
<% players.forEach((player, index) => { %>
   <tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= player.id %></th>
     <td><%= player.first_name %></td>
     <td><%= player.last_name %></td>
```

.....

This is not working.

In the top of the .ejs file, where I have this line:

```
<% if (players.length > 0) {%>
```

This line works, as I understand because, it at list prints "@" symbol, however nothing else is getting printed, when I refresh .ejs file.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using the sample from another stackoverflow post, may be my lack of knowledge in .ejs is why I could not see what I am doing wrong.

Code sample or a fix on how to display the bound data in .ejs file

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I would have to parse the database object, before binding happens. Here is how I changed the code:

```
res.render('index.ejs', {
                        "title": "Welcome to Socka | View Players",
                        "players":JSON.parse(datas)
```

Now I can see the data in .ejs file, without changing anything else.

Thanks.